# Are octopus merges possible in mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial

Is this possible in mercurial?
(As far as I know, no.)

How does the `hggit` extension handle octopus merges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but `hggit` just converts them to individual 2:1 merges of each parent branch.